# url rewrite about apache2.4.23

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I update my apache to 2.4.23

url like this:

> http://example.com/**products**/0/12365

I use this ruler ,it doesn't works

```
RewriteRule ^<b>products</b>/([0-9])/([0-9]{5,})$ products.php?name=products.html&page=$1&id=$2
```

but I change it like this
url like this:

> http://example.com/**product**/0/12365

the ruler like this, it works

```
RewriteRule ^<b>product</b>/([0-9])/([0-9]{5,})$ products.php?name=products.html&page=$1&id=$2
```

it seams s/ is a bug?
or anyone know how to do???

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer
because there is a file,it's named products.php
and I change it with this name "product.php"
and I use this ruler, it works now
RewriteRule ^**products**/([0-9])/([0-9]{5,})$ products.php?name=products.html&page=$1&id=$2
but i don't want apache  check the file exists
how to do~~~~